# Set relation proper notation

Tags: notation

I have a set of items $I=\{i_1, i_2,...,i_m\}$ and a set of shops $S=\{s_1,s_2,...,s_n\}$. Each shop has at least one or more items and same item can appear in multiple shops. How can I mathematically write a function that results all items $\in I$ that belong to any $s_j\in S$? The problem is, I have an Idea of using partial functions, but it needs a set as input, in my case its single shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f:S\to P(I) \\f(s_j)=\{i\in I: g(s_j, i)\}$$
where 
$$g:S\times I \to \{true, false\}\\
g(s,i)\equiv ( i\textrm{ belongs to }s)$$

Comment: I have one question, why $I^2$? I suppose its a powerset of $I$, so shouldn't it be $P(I)$

Comment: Yes, you are right.